# Python social auth PROTECTED_USER_FIELDS issue

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have setup Python Social Auth as below,

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY = 'social.strategies.django_strategy.DjangoStrategy'
SOCIAL_AUTH_STORAGE = 'social.apps.django_app.default.models.DjangoStorage'
SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_PROTECTED_USER_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

my pipeline is as below

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)
```

As per the settings, if a new user log in with a social account, the user details should be created with first_name and last_name. what i am getting is a user with blank first_name and last_name. if i remove **SOCIAL_AUTH_PROTECTED_USER_FIELDS**  i am getting first_name and last_name when new user is created.

So how do i get first_name and last_name when new user is created, and never update those fields on next login?

Comment: This change should fix that issue https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/commit/0e411aa2a78136c99ffd36fde232ceef7eb252e3

Comment: Thanks @omab for fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody looking answer for this question..
Check if your protected fields from PROTECTED_USER_FIELDS are in USER_FIELDS = [...]

Comment: Is it possible to have a code snippet to make it more clear relative to the question ?